# Elasticsearch: How to query an array field using OR condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a few ElasticSearch documents, which contain an Array field.

I want to be able to search the whole index
To find the documents which firstly contains the array field,
 
and if they do, find those documents which contain the value to be searched.

**Following is my data -**

```
{
  "took" : 633,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "demo",
        "_type" : "1",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "anon",
          "nick_name" : "an",
          "hobbies" : [
            "reading",
            "writing"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo",
        "_type" : "1",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "anon2",
          "nick_name" : "an2",
          "hobbies" : [
            "playing",
            "studying"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo",
        "_type" : "1",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "anon3",
          "nick_name" : "an3",
          "hobbies" : [
            "playing",
            "writing"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "demo",
        "_type" : "1",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "anon4",
          "nick_name" : "an4"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get those documents whose hobbies array contains **"playing" or "studying"** value
ie. documents 2 and 3

**Following are my data creation queries -**

```
POST /demo/_doc/1
{
  "name":"anon",
  "nick_name":"an",
  "hobbies":["reading","writing"]
}

POST /demo/_doc/2
{
  "name":"anon2",
  "nick_name":"an2",
  "hobbies":["playing","studying"]
}

POST /demo/_doc/3
{
  "name":"anon3",
  "nick_name":"an3",
  "hobbies":["playing","writing"]
}

POST /demo/_doc/4
{
  "name":"anon4",
  "nick_name":"an4"
}

GET demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**The following query is able to get me single search, but how can I achieve Or condition?**

```
GET demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "hobbies": "playing"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot test it right now, but it could be something like this:

```
GET demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "hobbies": [
              "playing",
              "studying"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If your `hobbies` field is of type `keyword`.

**Edit:**
Following the example in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), it could be even easier:

```
GET demo/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "hobbies" : ["playing", "studying"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to resolve this using the following es query -**

```
GET demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "hobbies": "playing"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "hobbies": "studying"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if a document with hobby `"play"` would be matched by this query. If I remember correctly, `match` queries are analyzed, stemmed etc and not meant to be used for exact keyword matches?

Comment: Yep able to retrieve the correct resultsets of studying and playing hobby types

Comment: But would a document with `"hobbies": ["play"]` be matched by your query? Because I think the input to the match query is analyzed and stemmed. After stemming your query should effectively look for `"play" or "study"` and thus both documents would be returned.

Comment: Oh yea doesn’t work for “play” case, works for exact text match only I guess?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want documents with `"play"` to be matched by your query when looking for  `"playing"` - or not?

Comment: for my particular use-case I needed exact search, but can you share both use-cases? how to do both? when to use which query type?

Comment: Well, I'm by no means an expert, but from what I know you can use fields of type `keyword` together with `terms` query for exact matches (like in my answer) and fields of type `text` together with `match` query for analyzed, _fuzzy_ matches (like in your answer). At least that is how I used them so far. But I guess there is more.

Comment: yea just trying to migrate from AWS CS to ES, this one is new for me too, but any chance have you done scripting on ES on multiple indexes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966305/how-to-query-and-sort-elasticsearch-by-making-calculations-on-a-document-field

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method with operator.

```
GET demo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "hobbies": {
        "query": "studying, playing",
        "operator": "OR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```